# NetBeans Test Result window and JUnit5

Tags: netbeans, ant, junit5

When I run JUnit4 tests from within NetBeans the test results window is properly updated with the test results.

When I run JUnit5 tests from within NetBeans then nothing happens in the test results window. (The tests are run ok and there is expected output in the output tab.)

Ant target for J4 tests:

```
<target name="xxxx">    
    <junit dir="." fork="true" printsummary="true" enableTestListenerEvents="true">
        <jvmarg line="xxxx"/>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>
        <test name="${xxxx}"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Ant target for J5 tests:

```
<target name="xxxx">
    <junitlauncher printsummary="true" haltOnFailure="false">
        <test name="${xxxx}">
            <listener type="legacy-brief" sendSysOut="true"/>
            <listener type="legacy-xml" sendSysErr="true" sendSysOut="true"/>
            <fork dir="${basedir}">
                <jvmarg line="${xxxx}"/>
            </fork>
        </test>         
    </junitlauncher>
</target>
```

How can I get the presentation in test results window for J5 tests?

Does it have something to do with the fact that there are no test suites in J5 like in J4?